# Crash/hang during boot sequence after loading apple menubar items in Mojave

Tags: mojave, startup

Macbook Pro 15" 2018 32GB RAM running the latest addition of Mojave. 
90% of the time, when I start up my computer it hangs. This occurs after I’ve logged in but will result in either a black screen with an outline cursor that moves, or a spinning beach ball with no menu bar. I am convinced there is a problem with some program or system event that loads during the start up sequence. I can successfully boot into a clean simple separate admin account (that successfully loads some additional agents like dropbox, citrix, techtool pro) so it's something I've added to my main account. When I boot using Safe Mode, the initial Apple menu items load, through time machine icon, but then I get a spinning beachball. The initial menu items actually respond to menu clicks, but the beachball returns when I move outside that part of the menu bar. Boot with Diagnostic (D key) finds no issues.

Comment: Did you try and boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting) to confirm this?  But, your login items are under *Settings → Users & Groups*.  As for LaunchAgents and Daemons, issue the command `sudo launchctl list` for the full list of everything that gets loaded.

Comment: Tried safe boot and that results in maybe 60-70% hang but this time after drawing the standard menu items. Then I’ve got the spinning beach ball. What’s weird is, the available menu bar items actually work but as soon as I put the cursor to the left of time machine the spinning Beachball returns.

Comment: If that's the case, it's not what's being loaded;  you have an issue with the system.  I suggest redoing the question with this new info and not look for a listing of loaded apps.

Comment: Also run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) (Hold `D` while booting).  Be sure to [edit] your question with the results, include your Mac model, and memory and storage free space as well.

Comment: Updated the question with info requested. Diagnostic finds no issues. Free space is 1/3 of the 1TB SSD.

Comment: I went ahead and reinstalled the system via recovery boot and it's working again. But I do need to see if it will reboot...

Comment: Reboot post successfully booting after reinstall goes back to black screen hang with cursor. So it’s still broken. I may just give up and go from the pot to the fire by a clean install of Catalina. Thoughts?